# User changing display name making it relevant to each question he posts an answer to?

Tags: discussion

I just saw this answerer https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/27574/10527 had originally posted under the name "phpbb3rocks" the question was phpbb3 related

Now on this joomla related post he changed his name to ilovejoomla
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/27575/10527

They are new to the site, not sure what they're trying to do by changing their name every time they answer maybe increase their chance of an accepted answer? Not a big deal IMO unless they try and start spamming links, just wanted to point it out

Answer (score 2):

Good point. I can't really see the point in it. In addition, IMHO, name changes are quite problematic. It would make any comments added to the first question, that refer to *phpbb3rocks*, somewhat harder to understand, if the username has changed to something else. As the referred usernames in the comments are not dynamic, that comment would now be referring to someone, or rather a username, no longer in the comment list. That would make any context to the statements to have been lost, which is a shame.